# what's the simplest web server code using asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to learn asp.net core, but I found the examples are way too much complicated for me. Even for the new project created by templates, I see dependency injection, MVC, entity framework. I just want to write a simplest code using asp.net core and just output some hello world on web browser.

By 'simplest', I mean something like this in golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

The reason I like the code is that I can see that I should begin with net/http module and see what happens by the method of HandleFunc. 
The reason I hate current asp.net core examples is that I'm overwhelmed by so much new assemblies and classes at one time.

Could anyone show me a simple example, or a link to at simple example so that I can learn new concepts in asp.net core one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would advise:

1. Start with the [console app sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio) which will teach you the basics of DNX the new runtime
2. Then work your way up with an [empty web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Instead of "web application", choose "empty" to keep it as clean as possible.
3. Then I would proceed with [MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can ignore the Entity Framework stuff. Delve a bit into Dependency Injection 'cause it's core to how asp.net core works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 71):

ASP.NET Core has [Minimal APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/{name}", (string name) => $"Hello {name}!");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple webserver in one function with no IIS deps.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimpleWebServer
{
    class Program
    {
        /*
        okok, like a good oo citizen, this should be a nice class, but for
        the example we put the entire server code in a single function
         */
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var shouldExit = false;
            using (var shouldExitWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(shouldExit))
            using (var listener = new HttpListener())
            {
                Console.CancelKeyPress += (
                    object sender,
                    ConsoleCancelEventArgs e
                ) =>
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    /*
                    this here will eventually result in a graceful exit
                    of the program
                     */
                    shouldExit = true;
                    shouldExitWaitHandle.Set();
                };

                listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");

                listener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server listening at port 8080");

                /*
                This is the loop where everything happens, we loop until an
                exit is requested
                 */
                while (!shouldExit)
                {
                    /*
                    Every request to the http server will result in a new
                    HttpContext
                     */
                    var contextAsyncResult = listener.BeginGetContext(
                        (IAsyncResult asyncResult) =>
                        {
                            var context = listener.EndGetContext(asyncResult);
                            Console.WriteLine(context.Request.RawUrl);

                            /*
                            Use s StreamWriter to write text to the response
                            stream
                             */
                            using (var writer =
                                new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream)
                            )
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("hello");
                            }

                        },
                        null
                    );

                    /*
                    Wait for the program to exit or for a new request 
                     */
                    WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[]{
                        contextAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle,
                        shouldExitWaitHandle
                    });
                }

                listener.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Server stopped");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the Empty template: New Project/ASP.NET Web application, choose 'Empty' from 'ASP.NET 5 Templates' section. It will create a minimal web application that answers 'Hello world' to every request. The code is all in Startup.cs:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
}
```

If you don't use the full IIS, you can delete the call to `UseIISPlatformHandler()` and get rid of the dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler` from project.json.
From that, you start adding functionality like static files, default files, mvc, Entity Framework, etc. via Middleware.