# Lower-level, simple back-end development using .NET Core, comparing with PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-core, http, backend

This question might be very elementary since I haven't worked with `C#` or `.NET Core`, but in `PHP` you can create a simple file that only receives `HTTP headers`, does some processings and sends back other headers (and optionally a content) to the client, and AFAIK this is a very basic `I/O process` in back-end development that almost all back-end parts basically use it.

Are there any similar approaches available in `.NET` (simple, direct access to exact `in/out` - `send/receive` process and additionally, cookies and sessions) or you have to use multiple libraries and classes which most of them don't interact directly to `HTTP headers`, unless you define a seperate class to gain such an access?

Also in `PHP` you can create multiple files and folders that work mostly separated. Are there also similar approaches available in `.NET` (e.g putting multiple projects in one server without any needs to change contents of those projects)?

Comment: `putting multiple projects in one server`...yep that's definitely possible, in almost any language. With .net generally you make them as separate sites in IIS (if you use IIS) or at least in subfolders / virtual directories.

Comment: `simple, direct access`...are you talking about just reading the raw HTTP request data, without using any of asp.net's various frameworks (e.g. razor pages, MVC etc) on top of it?

Comment: @ADyson Yes that's what I mean, but not fully RAW but something like `PHP` that puts headers in an object

Comment: Maybe something like this is what you need, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454074/whats-the-simplest-web-server-code-using-asp-net-core